# Proof that Eigenvalues are the Diagonal Entries of the Upper-Triangular Matrix in Axler

Tags: linear-algebra

This is 5.18 from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:

> **Theorem**: Suppose $T \in L(V)$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V$. Then the eigenvalues of $T$ consist
> precisely of the entries on the diagonal of that upper-triangular
> matrix.
>
> **Proof:**
>
> Suppose $(v_1, \ldots , v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ with respect to which
> $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix where the diagonal entries are
> $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$.
>
> Let $\lambda \in F$
>
> Then for matrix $M(T - \lambda I$) where the diagonal entries are
> $\lambda_1 - \lambda, \ldots \lambda_n - \lambda.$ We can suppose we
> are dealing with complex vector spaces. From 5.16 where have proven
> that $T$ is not invertible iff one of the $\lambda_k$'s equals $0$.
> Hence $T - λI$ is not invertible if and only if $λ$ equals one of the
> $λ_j$'s. In other words, $λ$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if
> $λ$ equals one of the $λ_j$s, as desired.

**Question:**

This only showed that one of the diagonal entries is en eigenvalue but not all of them as the theorem claimed.

Comment: $\lambda$ is arbitrary, as long as it is one of the $\lambda_j$. It shows one of them, but it is *any* one of them, thus they are all the eigenvalues.

Comment: Determinant of lower/upper triangular matrix is just product of it’s diagonal entries. (It can be observed from definition/property of determinant that involves algebraic minors)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I understand why this idiom (which is common in math writing) might seem confusing, but what the author is saying is correct. When he says that

> $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $\lambda$ equals one of the $\lambda_j$'s

he means that

> $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $\lambda\in\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$

or, to phrase it another way,

> $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $\lambda=\lambda_1$, or $\lambda=\lambda_2$, ..., or $\lambda=\lambda_n$

Thus, if I set $\lambda$ equal to $\lambda_1$, the right side of the biconditional is true, so that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ when $\lambda=\lambda_1$; and similarly with *all* of the diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.

Comment: Would you please explain how $\lambda = \lambda_1$ and $\lambda = \lambda_2$ and $\lambda = \lambda_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$? I still don't apprehend this idea?