# Stuck in finding Eigen values

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

The given matrix A is
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
2 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
I know that the Eigen values are the diagonals (2, 1, 3) as it is an upper triangular matrix (wouldn't matter if it was a lower triangular matrix). However, what is the Eigen values of:
$$
A^2 -2A + I
$$

Comment: It's eigenvalues not Eigen values. Contrary to somewhat popular belief, there's no mathematician named Eigen behind it. :)

Comment: @Little Child  in your case matrix is upper diagonal,so it's  Eigenvalue are diagonal entries http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264969/proof-that-eigenvalues-are-the-diagonal-entries-of-the-upper-triangular-matrix-i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that if $v$ is a vector such that $Av=\lambda v$ then $$(A^2-2A+I)v=\lambda^2v-2\lambda v +v=(\lambda^2-2\lambda+1)v$$

Comment: I found it on somewhere that for matrix $A^n$, the Eigen Value is $\lambda^n$

Comment: yes after diagonalization,eigenvalue of $A^n$ is exactly $\lambda^{n}$

Comment: @LittleChild you can show generally that $p(A)v=p(\lambda)v$ for $v$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $p$ a polynomial.

Comment: @MarkBennet The eigenvalues are [1,-2,4] ??

Comment: @LittleChild I get $[0, 1, 4]$ - $(\lambda-1)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Simply solve the quadratic equation $A^2−2A+I$ . Remember to take $I$ as one. This is just an easy way to remember.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps you to find the eigenvalues of $p(A)$ - if $A$ has eigenvalues which are roots of $p(x)$ then the corresponding eigenvectors are part of the null space of $p(A)$

Answer (score 1):

```
A=[2 1 -2;0 1 4;0 0 3]

A =

     2     1    -2
     0     1     4
     0     0     3

>> [V D]=eig(A)

V =

    1.0000   -0.7071         0
         0    0.7071    0.8944
         0         0    0.4472


D =

     2     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     3
```

$D$ matrix  contains  eigenvalues of $A$,related to your comment

```
B=A*A;
>> [V1 D1]=eig(B)

V1 =

    1.0000   -0.7071         0
         0    0.7071    0.8944
         0         0    0.4472


D1 =

     4     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     9
```

as you see eigenvalue of $A^2$ is simple $D^2$  and eigenvectors are not changed,but also please note that Lin your case matrix is upper diagonal,so it's Eigenvalue are diagonal entries