# How can you find eigenvalues without any calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can you see straight away, without any calculations, that 2x2 matrices like $A_1$ has eigenvalues 0 and 0 while $A_2$ has eigenvalues 1 and 2? *Is it because there is a zero in the left bottom corner and the number in the top right corner does not matter?*

$$ A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \\ A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
 $$

*Please don't use math-heavy reasoning, I have a very basic understanding of linear algebra.*

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264969/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803313/42969

Comment: If you write out the characteristic polynomial , you will notice why in fact the lower left $0$ is the reason and in fact the upper right entry is irrelevant.

Comment: An easier argument : The first matrix has determinant $0$ because it has a column containing of only zeros. We get such a matrix in the case of $A_2$ after subtracting $1$ or $2$ from the diagonal elements (in the latter case, we have a row containing only zeros). But this argument does not show that $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A_1$

Comment: This is because the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of the elements in the diagonal and therefor the characteristic polynomials are, respectively, $\lambda^2$ and $(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$.

Comment: I tried my best without any calculations and failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think [3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e50Bj7jn9IQ) made this recent video just for you!

Answer (score 0):

> In the particular case of a triangular matrix, the eigen values of the matrix are just the diagonal elements.

(Just calculate the characteristic polynomial in this case.)